# How can I check that all files on copied partitions are OK?

Tags: storage, partition, files, windows-8.1

I've moved my OS and copied another data partition to new SSD with AOMEI Assistant's "Migrate OS to SSD" and "Partition copy" respectively. How can I check that every copied file and partitions in general are OK? Is Windows 8.1 disk check tool enough? It's really important data, even a single damaged file can be a huge problem.

Comment: if  a single damaged file is a huge problem, you should re-evaluate your backup strategy before you worry about this. Any hard disk/ssd has ~1% chance of failing.

Comment: @camelccc This is not the only drive I'm copying files to. But I want to know, is there a utility, which can check every file, not only partition in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to check every single file, here's a way to accomplish it with Powershell:

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path (Get-ChildItem "C\*.*" -Recurse) | Export-Csv \\someplace\hashes.csv
```

This will generate a CSV file that lists every file in drive C, along with hashes.  Run it on both drives and compare the hashes.  However, a typical Windows installation has many thousands of files, and this could take a serious amount of time.  Consider narrowing the operation down to only files that you really care about.